# Unallocated External Drive Not Showing in My Computer

Tags: external-hard-drive

My WD Element external hard drive stopped showing up in My Computer when connecting it to the PC.

I tried to search for a solution, but nothing works.

In Disk Management, the New Simple Volume is disabled. The whole thing is unallocated, not just part of it.

[image: screenshot]

Please let me know what I can do in simple terms.

Comment: The drive needs to be initialized _(partition table created)_ before partitioning - either: (1) right-click on `Disk 2` → Initialize; or (2) `WinKey`+`R` → _Open:_ `DiskPart` → OK → `sel dis 2` → `clean` → `cre par pri size=<size> offset=1024` → `format fs=NTFS quick`

Comment: Most likely the disk is dead.

Comment: The disk is probably good, it is the enclosure that has failed, this is common for WD element brand of external disk.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the square to that says "Disk 2" and select 'Initialize'. Follow the defaults and hit next a few times. Then you can partition the disk.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If Disk Management doesn't give you any actions it can do on the disk,
not even the Initialize action to make the disk usable,
then it's quite likely that the disk is dead.

The disk should be replace.
If it contains irreplaceable data, a professional recovery service
might be able the salvage it. However, such services are not cheap.

Answer (score -1):

Can you do anything if you right-click on the 'Disk 2' part?

Otherwise, I would use a Third-Party program booted from a USB drive. I used minitool before but I dont know any free ones.

Comment: A drive needs to be initialized _(partition table created)_ before partitioning, which does not require third-party software. This can be done by either right-clicking on the disk name _(e.g. `Disk 2`)_ in Disk Management [`DiskMgmt.msc`] → Initialize or via `DiskPart` _( `WinKey`+`R` → Open: `DiskPart` → OK → `sel dis 2` → `clean` → `cre par pri size=<size> offset=1024` → `format fs=NTFS quick label=<name>`)_